# Git 403 Error on Pull, Previous Working Repo

Tags: git, github

I am using Git on a CentOS server. I have been able to pull and fetch from github with no problems. However today I am getting the 403 error on a pull request, the error states:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://username@github.com/CompanyName/ProjectName.git/info/refs
```

I have also changed the config file to include the password in the URL string just for  testing purposes (I don't keep the password in the string on a permanent basis) like this:

```
https://username:password@github.com/CompanyName/ProjectName.git
```

Unfortunately I got the same error. 
This is a private repo, and has never been public. When I use the same credentials (above) on my development machine, I can push / pull to this github repo with no problems via https

The version of git I am using on the server is:

```
 $ git --version
 git version 1.7.1
```

Going the SSH route is not an option for me, has to be over https. I have verified the remote is indeed correct, just for troubleshooting purposes I went over to github, copied the https url and pasted it in my .git/config file. 
I wanted to make sure I didnt have a UCASE/lcase issue going on with the URL.
Unfortunately that didnt work either.

Comment: Do you happen to be going through a proxy?

Comment: good point, but no I am not going through a proxy

Comment: Sometimes I also have the problem, that a command does not work any more. In my case, a `git init` helps.